# Is Javascript only available for web browsers?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

I would like to know about Javascript. Is Javascript available only for web browsers? Because I used some Javascript code for Firefox Plugin development and Thunderbird.

Help me to find out more about this: **where can I use JavaScript other than web browsers, and how?**

Answer (score 15):

There's [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) which includes a full webserver and runs on Google's [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)

Answer (score 14):

No! Have a look at Google's [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)

Answer (score 12):

Google Javascript. Click first link (Wikipedia). Click "uses outside webpages".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Uses_outside_web_pages

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of server-side (or otherwise non-browser) implementations of Javascript, including [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), which currently has a lot of momentum behind it, as well as the now-defunct [Jaxer](http://jaxer.org/), which provided a server-side DOM implementation based on Mozilla Gecko. There are also efforts to bring DOM type functionality to Node.js, primarily from [Yahoo](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/04/09/node-js-yui-3-dom-manipulation-oh-my/).

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo, Sadly, yes. They haven't produced a release for over a year, and no longer discuss development of the product. I'm pretty sure they've abandoned the product completely.

Comment: @Daniel, on the other hand it appears there's some regular activity on their GitHub repository, so someone may have taken up the slack. But Aptana is definitely not pushing it as they once were.

Answer (score 4):

With [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), you can embed Javascript in Java applications.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are definitely other implementations. For instance, JScript.Net is included with the .NET framework.

Comment: I've definitely heard of people using JScript.NET.

Comment: Ok. Then I should probably stop trying to make fun of it. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

MS-Windows can execute .js files (from the command prompt).

Since you do not have the browser context, you cannot use any calls to the browser (`alert`, for example, does not work).

Look for "[Windows Scripting Host](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232211)".

> WSH supports scripts written in
>   Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting
>   Edition (VBScript) or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

There are several implementations of stand-alone Javascript 
JSLibs (http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/) is general purpose
jsdb (http://www.jsdb.org/) is more database oriented

Comment: jslibs wraps many 3rd party libraries like zlib, SQLite, FastCGI, NSPR , ODE, libpng, libjpeg, librsvg, SDL, libiconv, OpenGL, OpenAL, ogg vorbis, libTomCrypt, ...

Answer (score 1):

Many text editors (including the one I use, ActiveState's [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit)) expose their APIs and let you write macros in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Using Adobe AIR you can write almost platform-independent Desktop Applications using JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

PDF files can also contain JavaScript code. See [first entry in google on this subject](http://www.nitropdf.com/help/pdf_javascript.htm) and also [Adobe JavaScript virus](http://drumlinsecurity.blogspot.com/2008/02/new-adobe-javascript-virus-acrobat-811.html).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can be easily embedded in applications written in other programming languages.

For Java there is as already mentioned Rhino, for C++ you can use for example [Flusspferd](http://flusspferd.org/). [Here](http://flusspferd.org/0.9/docs/tutorials.html) are some tutorials/examples.

Answer (score 0):

Qt has the [QtScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QtScript) module. From Qt 4.7 it uses JavaScriptCore (the Webkit JavaScript engine).

Answer (score 0):

In short, No.

Actually, Javascript and other Web technologies are used these days to create ***native*** *mobile and desktop applications.* (see [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) and [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/))

If you are familiar with the [KDE](http://kde.org/) project you can craft Plasma widgets using JavaScript, see [Creating plasmoids with JavaScript](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2010/116/PLASMA-BABY)

In Qt framework there is a QtScript module for JavaScript (ECMAScript) application scripting to provide much of the application’s functionality.

Also the new technology that is soon to be released in [Qt 4.7](http://qt.nokia.com/about/news/qt-4.7-and-qt-creator-2.0-technology-previews-released/) is Qt Quick, aka the Qt UI Creation Kit, which allows application developers to declaratively define their user interfaces in QML, for more information go [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/declarativeui.html) and an example [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoo_Ows1ExU&feature=related)

> QML is an extension to JavaScript,
>   that provides a mechanism to
>   declaratively build an object tree of
>   QML elements. QML improves the
>   integration between JavaScript and
>   Qt's existing QObject based type
>   system, adds support for automatic
>   property bindings and provides network
>   transparency at the language level.

And let's not forget Javascript is used as an *embedded scripting language* in various applications [OpenOffice.org](http://framework.openoffice.org/scripting/release-0.2/javascript-devguide.html), [Google Desktop Widgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Desktop#Gadgets_.26_plug-ins), and many others, see Wikipedia's article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Uses_outside_web_pages)

On the server-side Javascript enables back-end access to databases, file systems, etc (see [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), [Google V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), SpiderMonkey and others [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Server-side_JavaScript_solutions))

Answer (score 0):

Some document databases, such as [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), use JavaScript to interact with the database.